# sql server join query issue

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net, mssqlft

I am using this query for pagination

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {0} {1}) AS RowNum, * 
     FROM Cars 
     WHERE IdOwner = {2}) AS Rows 
 WHERE RowNum > {3} AND RowNum < {4}
```

I want to make the pagination query on 2 tables, not on just one as i do now.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {0} {1}) AS RowNum, 
            Cars.Id, Cars.Make, Cars.Model, Color.Name 
     FROM Cars 
     INNER JOIN Color ON Cars.ColorId = Color.Id 
     WHERE IdOwner = {2}) AS Rows 
WHERE RowNum > {3} AND RowNum < {4}
```

I am getting a `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`

Problem solved. Thanks guys, i am such a noob :(

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.Id  ) AS RowNum, 
       c.Id, c.Make, c.Model, d.ColorName 
       FROM Car AS c 
       INNER JOIN Color AS d 
       ON c.ColorId = d.Id WHERE c.IdOwner=1 ) AS Rows
WHERE RowNum > 0 AND RowNum < 11
```

Comment: What are the values of `{0}` .. `{4}`? You should use parameterised queries anyway not string concatenation.

Comment: Well, this doesn't address your question directly, but you should usually paginate in your program rather than in the database.  Load the relevant information into an array and then paginate from that.

Comment: @syrion: if you have millions of rows, you **don't** want to pull all those back to the client and then paginate......

Comment: @syrion - I completely disagree about that. As well as bringing back more data than you need how are you going to keep the array synched with the database?

Comment: One word: **PARAMETRIZED QUERIES!** - concatenating together your commands like this is a **highly dangerous** undertaking - SQL Injection Attacks are just around the corner.....

Comment: I totally agree with you, i just want to make this query work and after that i will use parameterized query

Comment: @marc_s: True.  I was thinking in the context of a web site where you tend to have 200 or so records at most.

However...

@martin: You can't sync with the database on every query anyway; if your results are changing when you switch between pages, you're highly likely to miss changes on the previous pages or skip over data when you paginate (because it has moved in the order of the query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c.Make is specified multiple times and "AS Rows" has been removed and is needed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.Id  ) AS RowNum, 
       c.Id, c.Make, c.Model, d.ColorName 
       FROM Car AS c 
       INNER JOIN Color AS d 
       ON c.ColorId = d.Id WHERE c.IdOwner=1 ) AS Rows
WHERE RowNum > 0 AND RowNum < 11
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be a bracket problem, and you have to prefix your IdOwner. Be careful to prefix your {0} and {1} parameter :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY {0} {1} ) AS RowNum, 
       Cars.Id,Cars.Make, Cars.Model, Color.Name 
FROM (Cars INNER JOIN Color ON Cars.ColorId=Color.Id) 
WHERE Cars.IdOwner={2}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like the {1} would be a sort direction. I'm not sure what the added parentheses will help (or hurt). You're absolutely correct, though, about making sure the columns get prefixed/qualified. Right on.

Comment: Well you're right, the bracket are probably not making good or wrong in SQL Server. I confuse with Access were the bracket could do a lot of damage if they are omit.